# Установка Linux Mint поверх ElementaryOS

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Имеется сломанная операционка ElementaryOS и я хочу удалить её и поставить Linux Mint, но при этом сохранив паку /home. В интернете не нашел информации по этому поводу. Сохранить эту папку на носитель не получится, так как она занимает очень большой объем памяти

Answer (score 0):

Переустанавливайте систему без форматирования данных. Пользователя создавайте с текущим логином и паролем.

Если сомневаетесь, то устанавливайте систему рядом - со сдвигом партишена, потом перенесете данные и сделаете переразметку диска с удалением старых данных.

Comment: а если есть сомнения, то можно имя пользователя другое взять и потом уже аккуратно покопировать.

Comment: Соглашусь с @KoVadim и добавлю рекомендацию. Всё снести и переразбить винт так, чтобы `/home` был просто на отдельном разделе. Тогда в будущем не надо будет ничего менять и можно прыгать с дистрибутива на дистрибутив без боязни потерять файло.

Comment: прыгать нужно осторожно. в /home каталоге ещё многие программы сохраняют свои конфиги. И есть ненулевая вероятность, что конфиги могут не сойтись.

Comment: А если у меня все на одном разделе?

Comment: загрузится с любого любимого live-cd, к примеру, убунту. Удалить все, кроме home каталога. Сделать переразметку. Продолжить устанавливать любимый дистрибутив.

Comment: Я б на вашем месте переименовал `/home/user` в `/home/user~` и после установки вручную перенёс все файлы в новую home. Иначе старые настройки как программ, так и системы могут создать проблем.